# Is there a way to launch Chrome Custom Tabs without actually displaying them?

Tags: android, google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs

In my application, we need to open a browser window and hit a URL - once the page is done loading we need it to close, which I know I can do with the CustomTab Callbacks. I would rather the user not have to see the Custom Tab open at all - is there a way to make it invisible?

We figured out how to do it with the regular Chrome browser, but I'd like to use Custom Tabs to utilize the warmup() method.

My iOS counterpart accomplished this same thing with Safari ViewControllers, which allow you to open one invisibly.

Comment: Um, if all you need to do is load a URL, why not use an ordinary HTTP client API, like `HttpUrlConnection`?

Comment: I need to load a URL so that the Javascript can run (which accesses a cookie which was set on Chrome previously).

Comment: It is currently not possible, but we would like to know what you want to do! Also, what is the "regular Chrome browser" solution? Is it opening Chrome invisibly from your desktop app or something else?

Comment: @EgorPasko is it possible to programmatically close the CustomTab? Like, perhaps, on a NavigationCallback?

Comment: The choice of closing the custom tab is on the user. An app should not (and I hope cannot) close it without user consent. The app can help the user to do what they want by providing custom buttons.

Comment: @EgorPasko Is it possible to completely hide the toolbar? thanks for your responses, they've been helping us tremendously.

Comment: @EgorPasko I've been trying to set intentBuilder.enableUrlBarHiding(), but that doesn't seem to do anything. I even ran the sample from https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client and selected "Auto hide AppBar" in the CustomUI example - and it doesn't seem to do anything. I don't see a difference in the sample app when toggling this checkbox. What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

In SafariViewController, it's easy to do it.

In ChromeCustomTab, You can use the [mayLaunchUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsSession.html#mayLaunchUrl%28android.net.Uri,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.util.List%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E%29)  method and provide the URL.
As the name suggests, the URL may not be always invoked. This is closest that I could find for "invisible browser window".

Comment: Yeah that's just for "pre warming" the url with DNS lookups, etc. As confirmed by the customTabs developers above, there is no way to do this at the current time.